# Fatal error: f_imageloadfont is not supported: NYI in HHVM

Tags: php, gd, hhvm

Getting the following error from gd using HHVM 3.7.1

```
Fatal error: f_imageloadfont is not supported: NYI
```

I couldn't help to ask as I didn't find any information about how to fix it.

This error did not happen to occur in PHP 5.3, 5.4 and 5.6 (didn't test 5.5).

**Update**: If you are [interested](https://blog.flowl.info/2015/f_imageloadfont-is-not-supported-nyi/) - [I opened an issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/5468#issuecomment-110818663).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main part here is `imageloadfont is not supported`, which means calling it will cause a fatal error like the one you're seeing.

You could open an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) about it to see if it can be implemented, or if the HNI definition can be removed so that a `function_exists` for it fails.